# Getting error "Argument of type 'typeof Header' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType...' or 'StatelesComponent'..."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

First, I'm relatively new to the react world having coded largely APIs for the majority of my career.  I'm building a react application for a non-profit and I'm just trying to get off of the ground.

I've added a header class as follows:

```
import './header.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as actions from '../../actions/authenticationActions';
import { AppState } from '../../state/appState';
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';

const logo = require('./logo.svg');

interface Props {
    displayName: string;
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    logIn?: () => void;
    logOut?: () => void;
}

interface State {

}
class Header extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props, state: State) {
        super(props, state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'Header'}>
                <div className={'Container'}>
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <div className={'Header__nav'}>
                        <div className={'userLogin'}>
                            <div className={'user'}>{this.props.displayName}</div>
                            <a onClick={this.props.logOut}>Log Out</a><a onClick={this.props.logIn}>Log In</a>
                        </div>
                        {/*<a href='https://localhost/' className={'button button--goBack'}>Back to Website</a>*/}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export const mapStateToProps = ({ currentUser }: AppState) => ({
    displayName: (currentUser != null ? currentUser.preferredName : 'Please Log In'),
    isAuthenticated: currentUser != null
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<actions.AuthenticationActions>) => ({
    logIn: () => dispatch(actions.logIn()),
    logOut: () => dispatch(actions.logOut())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

This largely seems to be fine, but it doesn't compile because of this error message:

> Argument of type 'typeof Header' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'ComponentType<{ displayName: string; isAuthenticated: boolean; }
>   & { logIn: () => LogIn; logOut: ...'.   Type 'typeof Header' is not
>   assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ displayName: string;
>   isAuthenticated: boolean; } & { logIn: () => LogIn; log...'.
>       Type 'typeof Header' provides no match for the signature '(props: { displayName: string; isAuthenticated: boolean; } & { logIn: () =>
>   LogIn; logOut: () => LogOut; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?:
>   any): ReactElement | null'.

I've battled with this for several hours now to no avail.  I'm fairly confident this is a noob mistake; please be gentle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error makes it seem like connect is really, really expecting a Stateless Component (although I'm not sure why).  You could try:

```typescript
import './header.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as actions from '../../actions/authenticationActions';
import { AppState } from '../../state/appState';
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';

const logo = require('./logo.svg');

interface Props {
  displayName: string;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  logIn?: () => void;
  logOut?: () => void;
}

const Header = (props: Props) => (
  <div className={'Header'}>
    <div className={'Container'}>
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
      <div className={'Header__nav'}>
        <div className={'userLogin'}>
          <div className={'user'}>{props.displayName}</div>
          <a onClick={props.logOut}>Log Out</a><a onClick={props.logIn}>Log In</a>
        </div>
        {/*<a href='https://localhost/' className={'button button--goBack'}>Back to Website</a>*/}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export const mapStateToProps = ({currentUser}: AppState) => ({
  displayName: (currentUser != null ? currentUser.preferredName : 'Please Log In'),
  isAuthenticated: currentUser != null
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<actions.AuthenticationActions>) => ({
  logIn: () => dispatch(actions.logIn()),
  logOut: () => dispatch(actions.logOut())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Comment: That loads... that makes me nervous though because ideally I was going to use state to hold the "isAuthenticated" property, and because I don't know why it's expecting a stateless component.

Comment: Generally speaking, I love Typescript.  Redux's implementation of connect can be very, very damaging to productivity though, because of how they've interfaced connect.  That said, I have a practice that my team follows to prevent exactly the type of errors that you're getting.  https://gist.github.com/JaSpr/502084fd5989b53760d93148cf67d864

Comment: By providing types for my mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps I'm able to tell typescript EXACTLY what the component I will be connecting will look like.  Otherwise (as in your case) typescript tries to infer what the component you pass in (Header) will look like based on its best guess based on those two mapping functions.  The more info you can give them up front (with MapStateToProps<ConnectProps, OwnProps, State> and MapDispatchToProps<ConnectProps, OwnProps>) the better

Comment: YES!!! This is wonderful!  After toying around with the gist I have it actually compiling and running!  thanks a million!  I'm not sure if I can update the gist with the small changes and fleshing out that stuff... looking now.  That is a great practice.  I love it!  Perfect time to establish standards.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument in the constructor is not State, it is context.

Header is not a valid React.Component because the constructor should be

```
constructor(props: Props, context) {
    super(props, context);
}
```

or just

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
}
```

unless you need context for something.

That said, you have typed it correctly with `React.Component<Props, State>`, because those two types are what are expected for the generic `React.Component` type, but those two types do NOT reflect what the constructor parameters should be (which is `props` and (optionally) `context`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I removed State entirely from the equation to the way you wrote that.. but I'm still getting the same error. Anything else that stands out?

Comment: No, the generic definition is correct.  Now, you're not actually using State anyway, so you *can* remove it from the generic type definition, but if you *were* to utilize state, and therefore your State interface had properties, then the way you implement it is correct.

Comment: Be sure it is exactly the same error.  TypeScript can give *very* detailed (and therefore hard to distinguish) type errors for React components.  Usually the last line in the error has the specific problems that need to be resolved.

Comment: Argument of type 'typeof Header' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{ displayName: string; isAuthenticated: boolean; } & { logIn: () => LogIn; logOut: ...'.
  Type 'typeof Header' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ displayName: string; isAuthenticated: boolean; } & { logIn: () => LogIn; log...'.
    Type 'typeof Header' provides no match for the signature '(props: { displayName: string; isAuthenticated: boolean; } & { logIn: () => LogIn; logOut: () => LogOut; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.

Comment: Do you get this error from it trying to connect? (e.g. is it caused by the last line in your example)? or from trying to actually use Header in your JSX? (e.g. from <Header />)

Comment: Yeah, just that last line.  Other than that bit the rest of the code seems to compile just fine.

Comment: From the looks of it, Typescript is expecting Header to be a stateless component, instead of a stateful component (React.StatelessComponent versus React.Component).  That said, from the looks of Header, there's no reason it can't be stateless (simply a method instead of a class)

Comment: Other than that, it may be your `Dispatch<actions.AuthenticationActions>` type declaration that's buggin things up.   I generally just do `mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ...`